# Reading a text file with double space delimiter in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Hi I am trying to read a txt file in R but the problem is that the columns are separated by a double space. I know that the read.table can read tapped files. The problem in my case is that some character variables have a single space, i.e. "New York" so I need to separate the columns based on double space not just any space.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple R programming question and StackOverflow is the place for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the lines of your text file with the `readLines` function. This returns a character vector where each element corresponds to a line. You can split these strings with the `strsplit` function. Finally, you can combine the strings to a matrix with the `rbind` function.

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit("filename.txt", "  "))
```

If you need a data frame, you can convert the matrix with the function `as.data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you Sven. I have used this and in works. For some reason after I use the readLines I get a \001 in front of every variable instead of a space but I use this as a separator and it works fine

Answer (score -2):

You can specify the delimiter in `read.table` and pass a [regular expression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html).

Example:

```
read.table(YourData, sep = "\s\s")
```

Edit: apparently you can't pass '\s' despite being able to pass '\t'

Comment: I've tried this but I get an error because it is an invalid separator. Did I do something wrong? Thanks for the comment

Comment: You cannot pass a regular expression to `sep`.  It must be a single character.  `"\s"` does not work because `nchar("\\s"); cat("\\s")`

Comment: because `\t` is a single character.  Control characters are different.  Typing `"\s"` triggers an error, where `"\t"` does not.